# SQL Parameter as DBNull.Value is not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm loading a select box list with a distinct list of values from our database table on `CompanyName`.

[image]

If the value in the column is `NULL`, I am adding '-- NULL --'

If the value in the column is empty or white space, I'm adding '-- EMPTY / WHITE SPACE --'

Otherwise, it will be the value in the column.

When I am trying to update the parameter to the property value `DBNull.value` is not working.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT Column1
      ,Column2
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,RestOfColumns...
  FROM [dbo].[CompanyTable]
  where CompanyName = @DataVisParam
```

Here is my code:

```
        public DataTable GetDataVisQueryParameterizedResults(string query, string parameterizedSelectedValue, string connectionString)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionUtilities.GetWebConfigConnectionString(connectionString)))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                    sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    SqlParameter param = sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SharedUtilities.DataVisParameterPlaceholder(), SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                    /*if (parameterizedSelectedValue == SharedUtilities.DataVisParamSelectBoxValueIsNull())
                    {
                        param.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else*/
                    if (parameterizedSelectedValue == SharedUtilities.DataVisParamValueSelectBoxIsEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
                    {
                        param.Value = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        param.Value = parameterizedSelectedValue;
                    }

                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
```

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Data Vis parameterized query placeholder.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Data vis parameterized placeholder text that will be used in the data vis query</returns>
        public static string DataVisParameterPlaceholder()
        {
            return "@DataVisParam";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Data vis parameter value is null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Parameter value for null on the select box</returns>
        public static string DataVisParamSelectBoxValueIsNull()
        {
            return "-- NULL --";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Data vis parameter value is empty or white space.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Parameter value for empty or white space on the select box</returns>
        public static string DataVisParamValueSelectBoxIsEmptyOrWhiteSpace()
        {
            return "-- EMPTY / WHITE SPACE --";
        }
```

I've tried `DBNull.Value` and not even setting it, but always 0 records are return for `NULL`. If I do the empty or white space, it works and 2 records are returned. Everything else is working fine.

Thoughts?

**Main Question: Is there a way to NOT have to change the query from `= @DataVisParam` to `IS NULL` ?**. I really do not want to have to change the query because then I have to make sure they put the text in perfect. I was hoping I could use the `sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add()` to check for `NULL`, but that appears it is not possible.

I've tried `DBNull.Value` in the commented out part of my code where this line is: `param.Value = DBNull.Value;` is set. It should enter this If statement.

Update: Yes, I know in SQL that you usually check `IS Null` for thanks in SSMS. Do I need to change my actual query from `= @dataVisParam` to `Is Null`? If I need to do that, doesn't that mess up the issue with SQL injection?

Update 2:

Appears I just need to replace the text `= @DataVisParam` with `IS NULL` when **-- NULL --** is selected in the select box

Comment: Its really not clear what you are asking. My best guess is that you are not familiar with how to compare against NULL in SQL? Maybe you want `where CompanyName = @DataVisParam or @DataVisParam is null`? Or `where CompanyName = coalesce(@DataVisParam,'')`? Or??

Comment: exactly where DBNull.Value is not working?

Comment: in SQL, a `WHERE somecolumn = NULL` will never return any result. Comparing to NULL with `=` is always false, you need `WHERE somecolumn IS NULL`

Comment: Does your column have a DEFAULT clause?

Comment: @DaleK: I knew how to do it in SQL SSMS. I was just curious if there was a way to do it without changing the actual Query. Appears there is not.

Comment: @TimRoberts: What do you mean `DEFAULT` clause?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE TBL ( somecolumn INTEGER DEFAULT 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with a co-worker, since we are replacing the query to `IS NULL` from `= @DataVisParam` and we are NOT using user selection / input, then we can accept the fact that there is not a possibility of a security risk.

The one downside to this, is the user that inputs the query must make sure they put the parameter correctly so that we can match it and replace it with `IS NULL`

```
        public DataTable GetDataVisQueryParameterizedResults(string query, string parameterizedSelectedValue, string connectionString)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionUtilities.GetWebConfigConnectionString(connectionString)))
            {
                conn.Open();

                // update the query with IS NULL to check on null values
                if (parameterizedSelectedValue == SharedUtilities.DataVisParamSelectBoxValueIsNull())
                {
                    // replace the param with IS NULL -> replace for one space or two spaces (if there is a typo mistake with updating the query etc.)
#pragma warning disable CA1307 // Specify StringComparison
                    query = query.Replace("= @DataVisParam", "IS NULL").Replace("=  @DataVisParam", "IS NULL");
#pragma warning restore CA1307 // Specify StringComparison
                }

                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    // the parameterizedSelectedValue is not Null, query by the parameter and query will not be changed.
                    if (parameterizedSelectedValue != SharedUtilities.DataVisParamSelectBoxValueIsNull())
                    {
                        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                        sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlParameter param = sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SharedUtilities.DataVisParameterPlaceholder(), SqlDbType.NVarChar);

                        if (parameterizedSelectedValue == SharedUtilities.DataVisParamValueSelectBoxIsEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
                        {
                            param.Value = string.Empty;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            param.Value = parameterizedSelectedValue;
                        }
                    }

                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }

            return dt;
        }
```